# What is the user type/role we need to have to be able to create new site collection inside sharepoint online office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, managed-account

We are starting a new sharepoint online office 365 project. now all the previous projects we worked on were on-premises 2013 & 2016. and we always ask our customer's system admin to provide us with at-least one manage account for sharepoint farm. then we use this managed account to create new site collections and access the central administration site. now inside the current sharepoint online project, we asked our customer to provide us with a username. But when we login using this username, we found that this user is a normal user, as we can only read the defualt site collection, but we can not add new site collections, and we can not access the default site collection settings.
so can anyone adivce what is the correct user type/role we need to ask our customer's system admin for ? so that we can create new site collections and manage the farm services inside our sharepoint online project?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to ask your customer for the Office 365 SharePoint Administrator role. This will give you access to the SharePoint tenant administration where you can create Site Collections and manage other settings for SPO. You will also want to have them add you explicitly as a Term Store admin in order to manage the MMS in SPO.